# Centering a Div inside another Div. I have tried everything

Tags: css, html, centering

I am trying to center a div inside another div in which the parent div has a width of 100% and a height of 100px.  I have research this thoroughly and I have tried all of the answers but nothing is working.  I think something is wrong with my code.

Here is what I have so far.

My HTML:

```
<div class="footer">

  <div class="footerContainer">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footerContainer    {width: 964px; 
                     height: 100px; 
                     margin: 0 auto; 
                     color:#9F0; 
                     right:0;
                     left:0;
                     display:table-cell}

.footer  {background-color:#1e4da0;
          height:300px;
          width:100%;
          left:0;
          right:0;
          position:absolute;
          display:table}
```

Comment: You **have not** tried everything. : https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&hl=fr&newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=centering+div+inside+div

Comment: Your width is 100%, it will not center as it is the same width.

Comment: text-align: center; ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; text-align: center;">
    <div>Your content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i could only do it with one extra wrapper. check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMyuJ/2/)
Also, i changed the dimensions and used some awful colors.
You'll have someting like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footerContainer">
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple fiddle example you may wanna have a look at it [http://jsfiddle.net/EZg6q/]